# Синопсис к киносценарию или синопсис киносценария?

Tags: падежи, управление

Или оба варианта годны к употреблению?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Синопсис* - краткий пересказ сюжета, а не документ (как в научном контексте), поэтому "киносценари**я**" или фильма. Вообще, это ненужное слово, поскольку любому понятнее "**сюжет** фильма". Словари (в отличие от википедий) это слово пока что не жалуют в применении к кинематографу. В таком контексте оно воспринимается как выхваченное автором из английского комментария к фильму и понятое как нечто новое и непереводимое.

Answer (score 2):

**Синопсис киносценария** — краткое изложение уже существующего киносценария для  продюсера фильма.

https://kinoscenariy.com/pishem-pravilnyj-sinopsis/